# Need Help in Self in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone please explain this code to as why it is written abc.name instead of mysillyobject.name?

```
class Person:
  def __init__(mysillyobject, name, age):
    mysillyobject.name = name
    mysillyobject.age = age

  def myfunc(abc):
    print("Hello my name is " + abc.name)

p1 = Person("John", 36)
p1.myfunc()
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_self.asp

Comment: because you've given both `self` parameters wierd names, they're equivalent. w3schools is terrible.

Comment: It's not that terrible, it can be be a great bad example. Just like in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def myfunc(self):
    print("Hello my name is " + self.name)

p1 = Person("John", 36)
p1.myfunc()
```

**Output: Hello my name is John**

Please see-->
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

> Function and Method Arguments
>
> Always use self for the first argument to instance methods.
>
> Always use cls for the first argument to class methods.
>
> If a function argument's name clashes with a reserved keyword, it is
> generally better to append a single trailing underscore rather than
> use an abbreviation or spelling corruption. Thus class_ is better than
> clss. (Perhaps better is to avoid such clashes by using a synonym.)

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the input parameter of the second function being 'abc'. If you change the input to 'self' parameter, it should work with self.name.